# MySQL Select statement returns no results

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Simple query, i have a table with clientID and cardKey. One client can have many cards. Query is to find all cards belonging to client 1

I am using mysql work bench, it executes the query normally with no errors but returns no results

```
SELECT cID, cardKey 

FROM client_cards

where `cID` = 1 ;
```

Comment: Nothing matches the `where` clause.  This is pretty obvious.

Comment: Even if i see it in the column ?

Comment: . . What you see is not necessarily what you get.  You might try `where cid like '%1%'` in case the value is a string with hidden characters.

Comment: a stored procedure with the same query returns key values, i replaced the in param with the same cID and it doesnt return any results. So that is not correct.

Comment: It is difficult to help when we don't even know what the table looks like, e.g. what are the column types, and what data is in it?

Comment: Without seeing the sproc, the table, a representative data set, etc, I'm not sure how you think we would be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct, but in the client_cards table there is no row that has cID = 1.

Comment: is my logic wrong? In the cID column i can see a cID of 1 multiple times for each card that clients has.